# Ats application api not working in insecured apache hadoop3 cluster

Tags: hadoop-yarn

Below URL return empty results {"entities":[]}
http::/ws/v1/timeline/TEZ_APPLICATION/

yarn.acl.enabled=true

But error is

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: null is not allowed to get the timeline entity { id: tez_application_<app-id>, type: TEZ_APPLICATION }.
```

I think this is about incoming user and not acl as username is null in above error
This was working fine in hadoop2 with same configs.

To find why authenticated user is null and if we can change it so that I can add it in acls.
Also why it was working in hadoop2